# Passing variable to another android activity using intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, twitter-fabric

I am new to using Android Studio and coding in Java.

I created a Twitter log in button using Fabric and I want to create a new activity to show the user's twitter feed. I need to pass the TwitterSession result variable to make API calls in the other activity, but I don't know which function to use to pass it.

I created a new intent and looked into using putExtra() to pass the variable, but I don't know what to pass it as. Serializable doesn't work when I try to cast it back to a TwitterSession.

What should I use in order to pass this variable?

Comment: Could ypu provide us your code and tell us your problem in detail so we can try to help you with the problem which stops you from going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call api twitter on layout login, then save result to  [SharePreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). then in another class just enough to read from sharepreference

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make your twitterSessionResult variable static in your LogInActivity and access it in you new Activity via: LogInActivity.twitterSessionResult.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result variable is not a constant, so I can't make it static. Very interesting idea however, I'll be sure to use it later in my project